# Apache load balancer logging question

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, logging

I am using Apache as a load balancer and would like to log the server to which the load balancer is forwarding the request to. For example, if I had three webservers, called:

- webserver1 - 192.168.0.1
- webserver2 - 192.168.0.2
- webserver3 - 192.168.0.3

I would like the log to show me to which server the request was forwared to (denoted by **bold**):

> 10.1.0.1 **192.168.0.1** - - [20/Jul/2010:10:52:01 -0600] "GET /js/shared/kobj-static.js HTTP/1.1" 302 236 "http://www.google.com/search?q=baked+bbq+rib+recipes&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.6) Gecko/20100625 Firefox/3.6.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729) infoCard/AzigoLite/0.0.12"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Custom log format to do that. One way I think you can do is to add the environment variable to the log.
mod_proxy_balancer (that I suppose you are using) exports BALANCER_WORKER_NAME variable that is the name of the Worker used for the request. You can use the `%{BALANCER_WORKER_NAME}e` directive on your Custom Log format string to get that logged. This is an example of the default debian 'combined' log format with the directive added:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" \"%{BALANCER_WORKER_NAME}e\"" combined
```

Comment: That did it.. I greatly appreciate the quick response and help.

Regards